# создание модели прогнозирования

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, csv, анализ-данных

Есть csv файл с данными `id, месяц, 49 аргументов`, которые неизвестно как влияют на проноз, второй csv файл, в котором есть `id`, и прогноз ( 0 или 1 )
С условия задачи не совсем понятно, но попробую в кратце описать. Есть input csv, в котором каждому id из result csv соответствует 12 строк значений, то есть к id 0 который завен 1 или 0, из результата, в инпуте соответствует 12 строк со значениями. как понимаю из требования задания нужно построить модель, на абонентах(id) целевая метка по которым находится в output csv

Как можно создать метод прогнозирования данных?
[image: output]
[image: input]

Comment: С таким описанием вам к экстрасенсам.

Answer (score 1):

В библиотеке `scikit-learn` полно разных классификаторов (а у вас именно задача классификации). Самый простой метод - это [LogisticRegression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression), начините с него.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True) # --> тут вам надо подставить свои X и y 
clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0).fit(X, y)
clf.predict(X[:2, :])
# array([0, 0])
clf.predict_proba(X[:2, :])
# array([[9.8...e-01, 1.8...e-02, 1.4...e-08],
#       [9.7...e-01, 2.8...e-02, ...e-08]])
clf.score(X, y)
# 0.97...
```

Первый dataset вам надо загрузить в `X`, второй в `y`. Ну там могут быть ещё тонкости, но копать надо в эту сторону. В частности `id` надо отбросить, предварительно убедившись, что его значения и порядок в обоих датасетах совпадают.

Comment: Спасибо большое за верное направление. С условия задачи не совсем понятно, но попробую в кратце описать. Есть input csv, в котором каждому id из result csv соответствует 12 строк значений, то есть к id 0 который завен 1 или 0, из результата, в инпуте соответствует 12 строк со значениями. как понимаю из требования задания нужно построить модель, на абонентах(id) целевая метка по которым находится в output csv

Comment: Картинки у меня не показывает. Когда одному результату соответствует много исходных строк подход может быть разный. Либо "схлопывать" их в одну длинную строку, либо каждой такой строке сопоставлять целевое значение, надо смотреть на данные, пробовать всякое

Comment: Для начала можете взять по одной (любой, хоть первой) строке из этих 12 и попробовать на них  что получится. Data Science это исследовательская работа всегда, готовые рецепты помогают только на очень стандартных задачах. Любая нетиповая задача требует исследовательского подхода. Know your data.